# Check if a domain is available via Route 53 without logging in?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

One way of checking if a domain is available through AWS Route 53 is to login, and type the desired domain into the 'Register domain' field:

[image]

Since this information is the same for all users, it seems login wouldn't be necessary to see the availability of domains; is there any way to view a domain's (un)availability through Route 53 *without* first logging into one's AWS account? (through CLI or browser)

#### Why?

It may seem an odd question since it's not overly time consuming to sign in and authenticate via authenticator app or another 2nd factor etc, but since that takes a minute and a public search form would only take a few seconds, I thought I'd ask.

#### What I know so far

One could search on (any) other domain name registrar, however, 3 conditions would have to be met:

- It must offer no domains Route 53 doesn't
- It must offer all the domains Route 53 does
- It must not [snatch](https://techpenny.com/registrars-available-domains/) domains (register them shortly after they've been searched for)

Comment: You could do the same search with a different Domain Name Registrar (eg GoDaddy). They all resolve to the same TLD (top-level domain) server. Selling domain names is not Amazon's core business.

Comment: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/route53domains.html#Route53Domains.Client.check_domain_availability

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Are you 100% sure other registrar's will offer the same domains as AWS (I ask because many times I've tried to buy a domain via Route 53 and it wasn't, so had to go elsewhere). Will that be a problem? Ideally I'd like access to the 'Register domain' field, but not behind a login, to enable quick checks as required.

Comment: Yes. It is not possible to register a domain that is already taken. Therefore, any other domain registration company would be able to tell you if it is taken.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein but all the same TLD's? I thought they differed from registrar to registrar?

Comment: Yes. Many companies, for example, can sell you a `.com` or a `.net`. AWS does not have a monopoly on any domains.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein two things are required if I use your suggestion and use another registrar to emulate what Route 53 sells, 1. It needs to offer all that Route 53 has, and 2. It must not offer anything Route 53 doesn't. Another consideration is that some registrars are not trustworthy, and could [snatch](https://techpenny.com/registrars-available-domains/) a domain you searched for. I trust AWS not to do that, but am (way) less trusting of sites like GoDaddy. I'll update the question with why these don't solve the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any API calls to Amazon Route 53 must be **authenticated with AWS credentials**.

For example, when calling [`check_domain_availability()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/route53domains.html#Route53Domains.Client.check_domain_availability) via Python and boto3, or using the AWS CLI to call [`aws route53domains check-domain-availability`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/route53domains/check-domain-availability.html), the API request **must be signed by a valid set of AWS credentials** that have permission to make this API call.

While the AWS management requires a 'login', using the AWS CLI or an AWS SDK does not involve a 'login'. However, they do need to be given a set of AWS credentials for the API call to succeed.

#### Example

```bash
aws route53domains check-domain-availability --domain-name somedomainname.com --region us-east-1
# UNAVAILABLE

aws route53domains check-domain-availability --domain-name lksjdfhblsdjfljsdfknskdf.com --region us-east-1
# AVAILABLE
```

Comment: +1 for the help/suggestions. This solution still does require auth (and access to a CLI). Also not sure if it works on mobile? TL;DR solutions requiring login take about 10x what a web form would take. It might be possible for me or someone else to make a simple literally single page app that accepts a domain and runs your code server side and returns the result, but it's reinventing the wheel a bit. (really just making existing Route 53 functionality more accessible).

Comment: Running `aws route53domains check-domain-availability --domain-name <something> --region us-east-1` returned a result to me in about 2 seconds. That seems very accessible to me! Yes, it still requires credentials.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried from command line and you're right and quick and easy. I still would like to find a way to do this from mobile and will post back in future if I find one. Thanks again.