# aws route53domains check-domain-availability showing 'PENDING' for all domains in a particular TLD?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, amazon-route53

Using the [`aws route53domains check-domain-availability`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74327347/5783745) command on .com domains shows `AVAILABLE` or `UNAVAILABLE` as expected:

```
aws route53domains check-domain-availability --domain-name abcdef.com --region us-east-1
# UNAVAILABLE

aws route53domains check-domain-availability --domain-name fkjsldkfjlskdfjlksdjf.com --region us-east-1
# AVAILABLE
```

But on a .com.au domain it always returns `PENDING` no matter what .com.au domain I try

```
aws route53domains check-domain-availability --domain-name asdfsdf.com.au --region us-east-1
# PENDING
```

Any ideas on how to get `aws route53domains check-domain-availability` to work for .com.au domains?

Comment: Does it work if you retry the same domain again? Docs indicate it should.

Comment: @jordanm I wouldn't have guessed that. I'll try now and report back shortly

Comment: @jordanm ha, it does!

Comment: @jordanm such a simple thing yet it had confounded me. Thanks for the help

Comment: This seems like quite strange behaviour. I'm still unsure *why* this happens. Do you know if there's a way to run the command such that it provides the correct answer the first time (even if it has to wait, better to be correct than fast). (I had presumed PENDING meant someone had purchased the domain but the registrar was in the process of approving it, which is approximately equal to UNAVAILABLE)

Comment: It could be latency. Maybe try your query in a closer region, otherwise you can check it on a loop, assuming pending is always temporary.